# PowerBI: Getting Count of customer with more than 1 transaction

Tags: powerbi

I'm new to PowerBI.
Please help me get the total count of customer that has more than 1 transaction. I need to put the figure in a CARD.

Thanks.

[image: data]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with following measure

```
Measure = COUNTROWS(FILTER(SUMMARIZE(Orders, Orders[customer ], "Count_Transactions", COUNT(Orders[transaction])), [Count_Transactions] > 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more performant ways to do it, but this is easy to read:

```
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Orders[customer] ),
    FILTER ( Orders, COUNTROWS ( Orders ) > 1 )
)
```